# CFXML - "Premature end of file" when enablecfoutputonly is "yes"

Tags: xml, parsing, coldfusion

When I run the following code within a `.CFM` file on a server running ColdFusion 2018:

```
<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="yes">

<cfxml variable="test">
    <test>
        <child>test</child>
    </test>
</cfxml>

<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="no">
```

I receive the error:

```
An error occurred while Parsing an XML document. Premature end of file.
```

When I remove the `<cfsetting>` tags, it works with no errors. Why is this?

Comment: I checked your XML file and it is _well-formed_.  So the problem must be somewhere else, not part of this question. Can you post a larger excerpt of the XML that is causing the problem?

Comment: @zx485 What I posted is all the code in the file, besides `<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="yes">` on the first line, and `<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="no">` on the last. My standard procedure.

Comment: You've pruned away the problem.   Test what you've posted to be sure that it still exhibits the problem.  Add more until you have a [mcve] that still exhibits the problem.

Comment: @kjhughes That's what makes this issue so confusing to me; I haven't pruned anything. What you see here is all the code that I'm running, and I still get that error.

Comment: But you said in your comment that there was more.   ???   Post a ***complete*** [mcve].

Comment: @kjhughes you're right, I never suspected my `<cfsetting>` tags would cause an error, but they do. My post is updated.

Comment: Did you try putting the xml content inside `<cfoutput>` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is that the xml content is being take as blank. Use this.

Since you have your cfsetting tag to `enablecfoutputonly`, we can say that the `cfxml` tag can see the content only if it is enclosed in `cfoutput`.

```
<cfxml variable="test">
    <cfoutput>
    <test>
        <child>test</child>
    </test>
    </cfoutput>
</cfxml>
```

[Original Code](https://trycf.com/gist/944a8297226b29eea33e5711b14398bb/acf2018?theme=monokai)

[Working Demo](https://trycf.com/gist/bcb54688acab47eebf3b8b3037d6ea64/acf2018?theme=monokai)

Comment: I was unaware that cfxml worked this way. That also explains `[empty string]` being the output when I try to do the same with `<cfsavecontent>`.